# Kentico 10 - How do I update the username of an existing user?

Tags: kentico

Using a kentico 10 website with claims based authentication.  We have the facility to update their email address in the external system.  So what I want to do is update the user's email address and username by looking up based on the external userid from our sso platform.

```
var existingUser = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers().Where("ExternalGuid", QueryOperator.Equals, userId).FirstOrDefault();

if (existingUser.IsInSite(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName))
    UserInfoProvider.RemoveUserFromSite(existingUser.UserName, SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);

loggingInUser = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo(existingUser.UserID);
loggingInUser.UserName = e.UserName;

UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(loggingInUser);
```

I'm getting the error:
The user with code name 'ac.aa@test.com' already exists.

This is happening on that SetUserInfo line.  So I'm thinking there must be another way to update the username properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

Check if the user exists already:

```
UserInfo ui = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo(newUserName);
if (ui != null)
{
  // user exists with new username so don't continue
}
```

Check if the username can be used as a username (no spaces, special characters, etc):

```
if (!ValidationHelper.IsUserName(newUserName))
{
  // username cannot be used as a username
}
```

Check if the username is reserved or not:

```
if (UserInfoProvider.NameIsReserved(siteName, newUserName))
{
  // reserved username so cannot use it
}
```

I'm willing to bet the username is reserved or not valid which is why it is not saving.  The assignment you have done should work without issue.

It also looks like you're performing this update in a global handler so this could cause problems with a few things.  So you may have to perform that username update later on or simply write a record to a custom table and then update it from there based on the event of creating those records in the custom table.

So I'd debug through your code and verify it is working properly by removing it from the global event handler, if it works, then it's an issue with having too many things happen at one time.

Comment: Unfortunately bet lost :)  But I think you were correct in that there is too many things happening at one time.  Given I'm basically trying to change the username of the user logging in - it is not playing nicely.  So instead I've gone with the approach of letting the new user log in, then deleting the old user, associating the customer of the old record with the new one as applicable.  Handy to know about the username validation concerns though.  This will of course mean that anything associated to the user will need to be updated if we use more than customer/orders functionality.

Comment: Oh well.  Figured it had to be one or the other.  Good to hear it got you closer to getting things resolved.

Comment: It makes more sense now - what logon web parts are you using? Is the new value actually saved in the DB or you just see the original user name on the web site? The issue here can be that the logon page or web part are using the value from the field.

Comment: @jurajo we are using the WIF integration - so it goes off to our single sign on website and then comes back where we execute a CustomWIFAuthentication OnAuthentication method (overriding SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute).  We've tweaked the requirement a little now so we're now trying to update the username of a logged in user rather than handling it in the global event handler.  Will see if we have more luck with this approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using SetValue(string columnName, value) method, I just tested this one and it worked fine:

```
UserInfo updateUser = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo("NewUser");
    if (updateUser != null)
    {
        // Updates the user's properties
        updateUser.SetValue("UserName", "NewUserName");

        // Saves the changes to the database
        UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(updateUser);
    }
```

For some properties/columns, which are acting like "read only", you need to use the SetValue method like it was a custom field (API examples)

Comment: You may also want to do a double check to be sure the new user name doesn't already exist.

Comment: thanks @jurajo tried this but still no joy. Have rejigged my code as I don't think what I'm trying to achieve is possible within the OnAuthentication handler (which I acknowledge I should have mentioned in the first place).

Comment: @rui good point and thanks but the single sign on application is taking care of that.